# Angular 4 - use resolver for app component

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-resolver

I have just discovered the [resolver class](https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/), and find it very useful.

There are different objects I need to preload, depending on specific url.

However, in my layout (`app.component.ts` + `app.component.html`) I would like to use resolver in order to preload logged user data from api.

I know this component is not accessed via router, so at the moment I use `ngOnInit` hook.

**Is there any way to use resolver to preload data before the app component is rendered?**

Comment: Usually in the app component one would have only the basic layout and the router outlet. So if you would create a component that needs the data from the api and navigate to it you should be able to use the approach you want.

Comment: **1.** you need to implement the resolver interface to a service. **2.** put this resolver service to the particular route. **3.** on the routed component you should take the ActivatedRoute to subscribe to the data it has.

Comment: That's right @adrian-fâciu, simply will create a header component... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) is more suited to loading data for the whole app.

Since [Angular 12 you can use Observables](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/using-observable-in-appinitializer-40bm).

For `app.component` it looks like the resolver **does run** and waits for it to complete, but it just doesn't pass the data to the App component. However, that data **is** available to child components even if the `resolve` is defined at the top level. But APP_INITIALIZER is probaly your best bet if something truly needs to be loaded globally!